# Mediawiki -- change code tag to respect single newline?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Is there a way to force the `<code>` tag respect single lines in Mediawiki? I really don't want to have to use the Poem extension because then I think it looks ugly. For example:

```
<poem>
<code>
Here's a block of code.
With two lines.
</code>
</poem>
```

I think that looks a bit bad... Any suggestions on just allowing the code tag to do the trick alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. Just simply use `<pre class="code">` and this does exactly every single thing I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight which handles new lines fine, too.

Example code:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="css">
.class {
    some-css;
}
</syntaxhighlight>
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated